# Reading a file with unknown UTF8 strings and known ASCII mixed

Tags: c++, string, utf-8

Sorry for the confusing title, I am not really sure how to word this myself. I will try and keep my question as simple as possible.

I am working on a system that keeps a "catalog" of strings. This catalog is just a simple flat text file that is indexed in a specific manner. The syntax of the files has to be in ASCII, but the contents of the strings can be UTF8.

Example of a file:

```
{
    STRINGS: {
        THISHASTOBEASCII: "But this is UTF8"
        HELLO1: "Hello, world"
        HELLO2: "您好"
    }
}
```

Reading a UTF8 file isn't the problem here, I don't really care what's between the quotation marks as it's simply copied to other places, no changes are made to the strings.

The problem is that I need to parse the bracket and the labels of the strings to properly store the UTF8 strings in memory. How would I do this?

**EDIT:** Just realised I'm overcomplicating it. I should just copy and store whatever is between the two "", as UTF8 can be read into bytes >_<. Marked for closing.

Comment: You can just delete your question, if you figured it out already. Or post an answer, if you think it will be useful for other people.

Comment: The problem is nt to read them, but finding the closing double quote, making sure that it's not an element of multibyte encoding

Comment: @Christophe You're never going to get an ASCII `"` as part of a mult-byte character in UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it just in your UTF-8 processing method which you mentioned.

Actually, one byte UTF-8 characters also follow the ASCII rule.

1 Byte UTF-8 are like 0XXXXXXX. For more bytes UTF-8. The total bytes is start with ones followed by a zero and then other bytes start with 10.

Like 3-bytes: 1110XXXX 10XXXXXX 10XXXXXX

5-bytes: 111110XX 10XXXXXX 10XXXXXX 10XXXXXX 10XXXXXX 10XXXXXX

When you go through the character array, just check each char you read. You will know whether it's an ASCII (by & 0x80 get false) or a part of multi-bytes character (by & 0x80 get true)

Note: All the unicode are 3-byte UTF-8. Unicode currently use 2 valid bytes (16 bits) and 3-byte UTF-8 is also 16 valit bits.(See the counts of 'X' I listed above)

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question. Everything is a lot clearer now. I suppose this question can stay up for anyone struggling with the same issue.

Comment: UTF-8 was originally defined as encoding up to 6 bytes, but was later limited to 4 bytes by [RFC 3629](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629) for compatibility with UTF-16. The claim that *"All the unicode are 3-byte UTF-8"* is wrong. In UTF-8, Unicode codepoints **U+0000 - U+007F** (ASCII) are 1 byte, **U+0080 - U+07FF** are 2 bytes, **U+0800 - U+FFFF** are 3 bytes, and **U+10000 - U+10FFFF** are 4 bytes.  This is not to be confused with the 2-byte encodings used by UCS-2 or UTF-16.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for complement. I mean the "same as" is the bits that carries information. Like 1110XXXX 10XXXXXX 10XXXXXX are actually have 16 bits carrying information. I have implemented a UTF-8 to Unicode small tools, those bits there is exactly shifted to fixed two bytes long.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, and UTF-8 can be processed using standard 8-bit string parsing functions. So the entire file can be processed as UTF-8.  Just strip off the portions you do not need.